# Correct css and html

Tags: html, css

If someone can take a look at this link I want to have 2 music players next to eachother( I provided just the text). When I change the div class to the css I think is correct it works only my desktop ( 1 music player left the other player right side) and when I check on  my mobile devices it is incorrect ( both players left 1 is more left than the other. I hope this makes sense I am new this web design world so please be kind.

`enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/GsPop/73bzuqLr/

If I need to upload html let me know.

Thanks,
GsPop

Comment: The last column's CSS has "float:right".

Comment: Adding "*enter code here*" is not a proper way of fulfilling the "*Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code*" requirement. So I voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the enter code mistake I am new to this and I could not figure out if it was my code or a special jsfiddle code I will do some research on that.

tsg your comment The last column's CSS has "float:right" what is the correct code?

Thanks and sorry for my code mistake,

GsPop